# Effect sizes for longitudinal data outside range

Tags: mixed-model, repeated-measures, panel-data, effect-size

I have repeated measures (between 2 to 4 time points) for my outcome variable (brain size) for individuals between 60 and 100 years old. I now want to know what the expect change over time is per decade for individuals from 40 to 80 years old (effect sizes so that I can do power calculations).
I am not sure how to go with this.

I tried a mixed effects model (in R) with random intercept and then calculated the following (age is continuous):

("estimate of age*time" * "mean time" * "mean decade") / std residual error

so, in my case this would be : 0.005*1.8*45/0.09 = 4.5. That doesn't seem right....

I also ran a repeated measures correlation with age varying over time versus brain volume changing over time and the result was r=0.395, but I don't know how to go from this to effect sizes per decade...

Any suggestions? Thank you

Comment: Generally, repeated measures power calculation require simulation studies which in turn require that you specify the structure of the covariance matrix. I'm not seeing a clear description of the assumptions that would be needed to conduct such a simulation. The fact that you have varying numbers of observations per subject adds an additional level of difficulty.

Comment: Thank you. I have no experience with simulations, but I found the simr library in R. I now only include people with 3 time points. If I want to establish effect sizes per decade, should I then run simulations separately for individuals age 60-70, age 70-80 and age 80-90? And then extrapolate these effect sizes to people below 60 (since I do not have that data, but I assume a linear relationship)? Any help is appreciated in this!